# Using iCloud for core data sync

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

Mine is a background application. There are thousands of data that are stored in local storage and till now i've been syncing the data to a remote server using http post. I want to know whether it is possible for me to use iCloud to sync my core data and then is it possible to sync from iClod to a remote server. I just want to use iCloud for storage purpose. I meant can it be operated like Parse and other third party cloud servers. I'm stuck with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing iCloud with Core Data does for you is sync data between multiple devices that use the same iCloud account.

> I want to know whether it is possible for me to use iCloud to sync my core data...

Sync from one device to another, yes.

> ...and then is it possible to sync from iClod to a remote server.

If you're using Core Data with iCloud, you're still using Core Data, so any server sync you're doing now with Core Data will continue to work in the same way.

> I just want to use iCloud for storage purpose.

It does store the user's data on the iCloud service, though it can only be accessed through your app.

> I meant can it be operated like Parse and other third party cloud servers.

It depends on what Parse (or other third party) services you're interested in. Parse does more than iCloud, it's not really the same thing. If you would use Parse only to sync data between different devices, you could probably use iCloud. If you would use Parse in any other way at all, iCloud is not a replacement.